# Gnome Terminal: Ctrl key "sticky"

Tags: gnome-terminal, keyboard-layout

With my recent update to Ubuntu 17.10 (and still with 18.04), I encountered a strange problem:

In the Gnome-Terminal, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key seems to be stuck for a very short while after having it released. I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A, E, D, K,Y</kbd> a lot for command line editing, and it seems I'm typing faster than expected. The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is (although released!) still pressed and subsequent keystrokes have unexpected consequences.

I've been searching high and low for "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> stickyness" and the like but wasn't able to find anything I can configure.

How can I reduce the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> stickyness?

I'm using Gnome Terminal 3.24.2-0 ubuntu4 (and 3.28.1-1ubuntu1.1 on 18.04).

```
$ gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard repeat-interval uint32 30
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard delay uint32 500
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard repeat true
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but going over unanswered migrated questions: Do you get this also with another keyboard?

Comment: Yes, this is happening on different computers.

Comment: Ralph, could you please execute the following and see whether it makes any difference?  `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard 250` if not, try `125` and then leave a comment @Fabby

Comment: You probably meant '''gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard delay 250''' ?

Comment: Yes, sorry: copy-paste error.